# Nautilus mousepress+ctrl+shift runs command ln -s while dragging

Tags: nautilus

Sinds 22.04 Nautilus mousepress+ctrl+shift no longer runs command ln -s while dragging. How to I fix?

Now I have to open the terminal every time. Works great when I do things via Nautilus sftp website.

So, how do I get this working again?

Answer (score 0):

Dragging with `Primary Mouse` + `CTRL` + `SHIFT` still creates a link in 22.04.

Comment: Special, I have this problem on all devices. From several PCs, several Laptops and two Raspberrys. Only the PC that has been upgraded does not have the problem.